# Using Google API V3 to connect to Google Calendar

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I saw a post two days ago :
[google api calendar php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430525/google-api-calendar-php)

And it looks like the code I need. I am only an amateur php programmer. I had been using **Zend Framework** to connect my website to a Google calendar to make changes on the calendar from my site,but now deprecated as it used V2 of **Google API**.

So now I am trying to use the PHP client library and have gone to the Google Developer console and created what I think is an 'App' (service account) to use the php client library.  In the code in the above post there is  a line:

```
$client->setApplicationName("My app");
```

I am not sure what that refers to? I have a 'project name' when creating it in the console but I am really not sure if this is the 'App name'. Or worse maybe i am not creating an app at all and have made a mistake. I have all the other parameters like client ID, key file and service account.

P.S. I saw one post where you had to add client ID to the `../src/Google/config.php` file - is that needed as well?

thx

Comment: "MY APP" is just your application name. You can just add application name(not client_id) in the above line. Here is the link which helps you to connect to calendar Api v3 using php http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-php/

Comment: is the application name your Project Name from the console?  Also the link you gave the original code I referenced is not really what I need. After more study I think I need a service account, because I do not want the user to be interacting with the calendar I want the server to be doing that for them. So I need something more like [Ian's Blog](http://blog.iangsy.com/2013/10/writing-events-to-calendar-with-php.html#comment-form_6336616316706230010) that has the key file on the server and no client secret or key.  thanks for your comment

Comment: It is the name you give for your application. Is is just for your reference.

Comment: Or using the same blog you sent it is the [daimto.com - Service account Post](http://www.daimto.com/google-calendar-api-with-php-service-account/).

Comment: Just ot ask again - is the application name your Project Name from the console? If it isn't then I do not know what it is.

Comment: okay I got this working that reference to [daimto.com](http://www.daimto.com/google-calendar-api-with-php-service-account/#comment-1610) was the answer, thanks again. Wish I knew how to email ppl directly at this site to thank them!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found all the advice on setting up a service account and also the code for adding an event at [daimto.com](http://daimto.com)
App name can just be the project name form your Google console too BTW.

Comment: You should accept that answer as "one that helped you" :)